# How to extract the labels under some node with height in dendrogram?

Tags: r, dendrogram

I have a dendrogram and I would like to extract all the lables under a node that I already know its height. For example:

```
data = data.frame(point = c('A','B','C','D','E'), 
                  x = c(2,2.5,2.1,3,5), 
                  y = c(3.1,4,5,6,2))
d = dist(as.matrix(data[, 2:3])) 
hc = hclust(d,method = "ward.D2")
plot(hc, labels = data$point)
```

[image: Dendrogram]

And we know the height of the all the nodes:

```
hc$height
# [1] 1.029563 1.345362 2.790161 4.584430
```

Now I would like to know all labels under a certain height, for example, with the height equals to 1.029563, I expect the results `c("A", "B")` and with the height equals to 1.345362,  I expect the results `c("C", "D")`.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: See the `merge` component meaning from `?hclust`, section `Value`.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to `?hclust` you'd see the somewhat confusing explanation of what the `merge` component is. In the example you gave:

```
hc$merge
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   -1   -2
# [2,]   -3   -4
# [3,]    1    2
# [4,]   -5    3
```

And also:

```
hc$height
# [1] 1.029563 1.345362 2.790161 4.584430
```

You can see the node heights are in order from lowest to highest.
Therefore, the points combined under that numbered node are the ones lower than it:

```
for (node in 1:length(hc$height)) {          # roll over the nodes
  points <- hc$merge[1:node, ]               # look at the relevant rows
  points_under_node <- -points[points < 0]   # negative values are points
  print(points_under_node)                   # points numbers
  print(c("node = ", node))                  # node number
  print(data$point[points_under_node])       # point names under node
}
```

A bit iffy but I hope this gets the point across.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with your suggestion, the result I get seems different to what I expected. But I have made some others "iffy" codes to get what I want. I'll post it on later :)) Thanks again

Comment: @liverpool29 I edited the final bit, it should now print out the actual points `A` through `E`. This loop can be altered to perhaps save the points somewhere else, the print is just for show. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from @nicola and the answer from @Ronny Efronny, I tried to made codes that produce the results that I want (though they're not good looking):

```
A = hc$merge
labelList = c()
for (i in seq(1, max(clusters)-1)){
  if((A[i,1]<0) & (A[i,2]<0)){
    labelList[[i]] = c(-A[i,])
  }
  else if((A[i,1]<0) & (A[i,2]>0)){
    labelList[[i]] = c(-A[i,1], labelList[[A[i,2]]])
  }
  else if((A[i,1]>0) & (A[i,2]<0)){
    labelList[[i]] = c(-A[i,2], labelList[[A[i,1]]])
  }
  else if((A[i,1]>0) & (A[i,2]>0)){
    labelList[[i]] = c(labelList[[A[i,1]]], labelList[[A[i,2]]])
  }
}
```

Then `labelList[[i]]` gives the results correspond to the node with `hc$height[i]`.

It would be nice if someone can help me edit the codes so that they look more beautiful :))